# Exercise 5.26 of PRML By Bishop

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, neural-networks

This is the question:

[image]

Equations 5.127 and 5.128:

[image]

I am stuck on proving 5.206. This is my proof, and I am getting the wrong answer:

$\Omega_{n} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k} \left( \sum_{i} J_{nki}\tau_{ni} \right)^{2}$

$\Longrightarrow \frac{\partial \Omega_{n}}{\partial w_{rs}} = \frac{\partial }{\partial w_{rs}} \left( \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k} \left( \sum_{i} J_{nki}\tau_{ni} \right)^{2} \right)$

$= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k} \frac{\partial }{\partial w_{rs}} \left( \sum_{i} J_{nki}\tau_{ni} \right)^{2}$

$= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k} 2\left( \sum_{i} J_{nki}\tau_{ni} \right) \left( \frac{\partial }{\partial w_{rs}} \left( \sum_{i} J_{nki}\tau_{ni} \right)\right) $

$ = \sum_{k} \left( \sum_{i} J_{nki}\tau_{ni} \right) \left( \sum_{i} \frac{\partial J_{nki}\tau_{ni}}{\partial w_{rs}} \right) $

$ = \sum_{k} \left( \sum_{i} J_{nki}\tau_{ni} \right) \left( \sum_{i} \tau_{ni}\frac{\partial J_{nki}}{\partial w_{rs}} \right) $

$= \sum_{k} \left( \sum_{i} J_{nki}\tau_{ni} \right) \left( \sum_{i} \tau_{ni}\frac{\partial J_{nki}}{\partial a_{r}}\frac{\partial a_{r}}{\partial w_{rs}} \right)$

$= \sum_{k} \left( \sum_{i} J_{nki}\tau_{ni} \right) \left( \sum_{i} \tau_{ni} \left( 
\frac{\partial^{2} y_{k}}{\partial x_{i} \partial a_{r}} \right) \left(\frac{\partial a_{r}}{\partial w_{rs}} \right)\right)$

$= \sum_{k} \left( \sum_{i} J_{nki}\tau_{ni} \right) \left( \sum_{i} \tau_{ni} \left( 
\frac{\partial^{2} y_{k}}{\partial x_{i} \partial a_{r}} \right) \left(\frac{\partial \sum_{i'}w_{ri'}z_{i'}}{\partial w_{rs}} \right)\right)$

$= \sum_{k} \left( \sum_{i} J_{nki}\tau_{ni} \right) \left( \sum_{i} \tau_{ni} \left( 
\frac{\partial^{2} y_{k}}{\partial x_{i} \partial a_{r}} \right)z_{s} \right)$

$= \sum_{k} \left( \sum_{i} J_{nki}\tau_{ni} \right) z_{s} \left( \sum_{i} \tau_{ni} \left( 
\frac{\partial^{2} y_{k}}{\partial x_{i} \partial a_{r}} \right) \right)$

$= \sum_{k} \left( \sum_{i} J_{nki}\tau_{ni} \right) z_{s} \left( \sum_{i} \tau_{ni} \left( 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}} \delta_{kr} \right) \right)$

$= \sum_{k} \left( \sum_{i} J_{nki}\tau_{ni} \right) z_{s} \mathcal{G}\delta_{kr}$

$= \sum_{k} \alpha_{k} z_{s} \phi_{kr}$

I can't figure out where the error is.

Answer (score 1):

The regularization term is the (squared) norm of
$R = \frac12
\| \mathbf{\alpha}^L \|^2_2$
where
$
\mathbf{\alpha}^L
=
\frac{\partial \mathbf{z}^{L}}{\partial \mathbf{x}_0}
\mathbf{\tau}
$.

It holds
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{rs}}
\left[
\frac{\partial z_k^L}{\partial \mathbf{x}_0}
\right] &=&
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}_0}
\left[
\frac{\partial z_k^L}{\partial W_{rs}}
\right]=
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}_0}
\left[
\frac{\partial z_k^L}{\partial a_r}
\frac{\partial a_r}{\partial W_{rs}}
\right] \\
&=&
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}_0}
\left[
\delta_{kr} z_s
\right] 
=
\frac{\partial \delta_{kr}}{\partial \mathbf{x}_0}
z_s
+
\delta_{kr}
\frac{\partial z_s}{\partial \mathbf{x}_0}
\end{eqnarray*}
It follows
$$
\frac{\partial \alpha_k^L}{\partial W_{rs}}
=
\phi_{kr} z_s + \delta_{kr} \alpha_s
$$

\begin{eqnarray*}
dR
&=&
\sum_k
\alpha_k^L
d\alpha_k^L =
\sum_k
\alpha_k^L
\left(
\frac{\partial \alpha_k^L}{\partial W_{rs}}
\right)
dW_{rs} \\
\frac{\partial R}{\partial W_{rs}}
&=&
\sum_k
\alpha_k^L
\left[
\phi_{kr} z_s + \delta_{kr} \alpha_s
\right]
\end{eqnarray*}